# django method POST and Querydict

Tags: django, forms, post

In my template `choose_values.html` I have a dropdown list and I choose some values. I am able to pass these values as a QueryDict to a view `tomatos` by assigning request.POST to a variable.

I would like to use chosen values in a filter in view `tomatos`

I do not know how to extract chosen values from this QueryDict.

this is example QueryDict:

```
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'pFs9fj5MLQML7KLYHXFeCWTSvuMFEoML'], u'dropdown1': [u'project1'], u'dropdown2': [u'S1'], u'dropdown3': [u'S1.2']}>
```

how can I do it ?

choose_values.html

```
CHOOSE_VALUES
<form method="post" action="{% url 'projects:manage_values' %}">{% csrf_token %}

    <select name="dropdown1">
        <option value="project1">project1</option>
        <option value="project1">project2</option>
    </select>

    <select name="dropdown2">
        <option value="S1">S1</option>
        <option value="S2">S2</option>
        <option value="all">all</option>
    </select>

     <select name="dropdown3">
         <option value="S1.1">S1.1</option>
         <option value="S1.2">S1.2</option>
         <option value="all">all</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

tomatos view

```
def tomatos(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    ZoneSubFormSet = modelformset_factory(ZoneSubStage, fields=('zone', 'substage','value'),max_num=2)
    dupa=request.POST
    print dupa
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ZoneSubFormSet(queryset=ZoneSubStage.objects.filter(substage__stage__stage_name='S1',
                                                                      substage__stage__project__name='project1',
                                                                      zone__zone_name='z1'))
    else:
        formset = ZoneSubFormSet(queryset=ZoneSubStage.objects.filter(substage__stage__stage_name='S2',
                                                                      substage__stage__project__name='project1',
                                                                      zone__zone_name='z2'))

    return render_to_response('autostages/update_values.html', {'formset': formset}, context)
```

**EDIT**

I do not update values for some reasons and I do not know why.

```
def tomatos(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    ZoneSubFormSet = modelformset_factory(ZoneSubStage, fields=('zone', 'substage','value'),max_num=2)
    value1=str(request.POST.get('dropdown1'))
    value2=str(request.POST.get('dropdown2'))
    value3=str(request.POST.get('dropdown3'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ZoneSubFormSet(queryset=ZoneSubStage.objects.filter(substage__stage__project__name=value1,
                                                                      substage__stage__stage_name=value2,
                                                                      zone__zone_name=value3))
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save(commit=True)
    else:
        formset = ZoneSubFormSet(queryset=ZoneSubStage.objects.filter(substage__stage__project__name=value1,
                                                                      substage__stage__stage_name=value2,
                                                                      zone__zone_name=value3))

    return render_to_response('autostages/update_values.html', {'formset': formset}, context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with this QueryDict as a normal dict, in this case, for example, if you want to get the `dropdown1` value:

```
request.POST.get('dropdown1')
```

Comment: hi,  for some reasons I am not updating my date. can you help please?  I have updated the code in my post above and I can see I do not perform formset.save()